# How to mirror in sculpt mode?

Tags: mirror

I was working on a character legs with symetry enabled, as one leg was getting in the way I decided to hide it. But now that I unhided it, all the details are not in this leg.

My question is how to mirror what I have in one leg to the other one, just as I can do using dyntopo?

Answer (score 5):

1. Switch to **Edit Mode**, <kbd>A</kbd> x 1 (or x 2) to select all elements;
2. Press <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, search for **Symmetrize**;
3. Tweak *Direction* and *Threshold* in <kbd>F6</kbd> panel.

[image]

**NOTE:** A partial selection will simply duplicate / mirror the selection. In your case, you just need a correction, so you should select all elements first.

Comment: Or just delete half, add a mirror mod, the turn on clipping. thats what I do.

Comment: I'm still wondering whether there are other parts other than legs is asymmetric as intended. In that case, he/she has to only delete the needed part (delete nothing but all vertices of the leg on the other side, in this case).

Comment: That is correct, though a model with asymmetric face but symmetric pants would fall under category *odd*.

Comment: I tried that and now when I go to object and sculpt mode, the right side is over the left side, but that doesn't happens in edit mode of course. I also tried to delete one leg, copy the other one, mirror it and the same happens. And finally tried to delete half body, add a mirror modifier, apply it, it worked but every detail from the multiressolution modifier is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic topology offers a symmetrize function that copies the mesh from one side to another.

Choose the direction that you want to copy and then click symmetrize.

[image]

Comment: Bit out of date now but I think better than the current answer. For others, select "Active Tool" and there is now a dedicated Symmetry section with a Mirror X/Y/Z option.